# League of legends end of game stats

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Riot offer any way to keep track of the end of game stats via an XML file or something similar? They show a score grid that keeps track of almost everything; gold earned, damage dealt, largest critical strike, etc. I'd like to pull that data and make a graph out of it. I know how to do it if I can get access to that data so I'm wondering if anyone has heard either way.

Comment: I can't answer my own question, but I found what I was looking for. [Curious?](http://www.lolbase.net/champions?period=v1.0.0.87&server=all&level_range=all&map=all)

Comment: Not a game development question;  more a question to be asked of the LoL developers.  Perhaps on their forums.

Comment: @totbar you can answer your own answer just click answer button down there

Answer (score 10):

Totbar, I saw you commented above with [this link](http://www.lolbase.net/). As a LoL player myself, I used this site for a bit, until I learned that you had to do it almost every day or the logs would be outdated.

Also, if you didn't start doing it the *moment* you started playing LoL, the stats only reflect the logs you *have* uploaded.

I stopped paying attention to it because it was faulty.

Essentially, I'm sure your records overall are saved on the LoL servers somewhere (they have to be due to the takedowns calculation and stuff), but as of right now, and for whatever reason, this is not available to the players.

Frustrating, I know.

**Edit:** I just found a League of Legends statistics crawler! http://lolstatistics.com/

Thank me later. :)

Comment: Thats a very nice site, I used http://riotstats.com/ and was wondering about a better way!

Comment: lolstatistics.com and riotstats.com appear to no longer exist.

Comment: For anybody that is looking for the same kind of thing but that is still open and maintained in 2020, here: https://www.leagueofgraphs.com/