# Is there a way to retreive your hidden stats?

Tags: league-of-legends

The League client records many statistics about your battles. Some of these include who you played against, how long the game was, and other things like that. Often when I have a game end my client crashes, or I end up stuck at a 'waiting for stats' screen with an option to click a button and skip the wait.

In both of these circumstance my client does not display most of my information about the last game. Some of this information is often important to me. IE: The name of the Kat who afk'ed so I can report her. Or the number of assists my support had so I can post our game stats on facebook. Those are but two examples, I could write a thesis on how much of this lost information can be usefull.

Is there anyway I can retreive information that has either been hidden (too long ago in my recent matches list) or that was never displayed at all due to bugs or such.

Comment: Does match history not work for you? Also I believe riot has mentioned that you cannot report anyone outside of the stat screen after a game, i'll answer if I can find that source.

Comment: related, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25262/league-of-legends-end-of-game-stats?rq=1 might be helpful

Comment: @paralytic match history, and how it does or doesn't work, was mentioned in the question I thought, should I explain in greater detail?

Comment: I MAY end up vtc this as a duplicate, the the answers in the question @Paralytic mentioned contain many of the answers I'm seeking, however the website the answer linked to is down at the moment, so until I know for sure I'm gonna leave this question as it is

Comment: I forgot you can see in depth stats after a game and not in game history, i stopped caring about stats 100 wins ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [lolking](http://www.lolking.net/summoner/na/2038#history). The link there is to a summoner named Ender. I dunno if that is you but it is who I searched for because of your name. However, as stated in the comments I do not know of anyway to report another summoner outside of the match results screen.

Comment: There isn't a way, short of contacting Riot in real life, I just can't find a source proving this.